# Jar a folder that have been extracted from a jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have used Extrat to *name* from WinRAR to extract all the contain of the jar file and modified a line of code in the class with Cavaj Java Decompiler.
How do I jar the folder back?

I have tried methods such as 
for windows just make the folder as winrar file.,
to do this right click the folder and click "7 -zip" then
choose "add to foldername.zip".
now a rar file is created with the same folder name.
Then open the cmd in current folder directory
type "mv foldername.zip foldername.jar"

but the file turns to be corrupted and doesn't run.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot just make changes into bytecode and zip it back. you would need original java code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to extracted jar dir and run:
`jar -cvf my-jar.jar *`

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar    the input I can use is java jar -cvf nameofjar.jar * else it says jar is not valid